# Why is it when i go to .onion sites that I'm told that my connection is not secure or encrytped?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, security, connection

Okay so I'm fairly new to actually using Tor, but I have known about it for years. I have read many things on how to stay secure and anonymous while on Tor. I also have the Tor browser security settings on max, so the safest ones yet also the strictest. My question is how come when i visit a .onion address such as the hidden wiki why is it when i click on the information button on the left of the address bar say your connection is not secure or encrypted? Should i be worried and mainly how do i fix this ,or am i just worrying to much and this is just normal? I'm just excited and want to explore the deep web ,but more importantly do it securely and anonymously. So i will delay my exploration until this issue is resolved. Thank you all in advanced if you can help me with this issue have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

Every connection to a hidden service is anonymous and encrypted. This is just a UX bug.

---

The absence of a lock (or a "secure connection" message) just means that the site you're connected to doesn't uses TLS. However since your connecting to the site using a hidden service, the connection is encrypted no matter if TLS is used or not.

The UX of this has been improved in the current alpha version of Tor (See [Ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/23247))

**Screenshot of new UX**

[image: screenshot]